# unable to add a view to linearlayout inside viewpager fragment on clicking activity button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an `activity` with a `button` at the bottom and `viewPager` on the top. I have a `linearLayout` with vertical orientation inside the `viewPager` `fragment`. I am trying to add a view dynamically to the `linearLayout` inside `fragment` on clicking the `activity` `button`.

I am accessing the activity's `button` inside the `fragment`:

```
Button button = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

When I `click` the above `button`, `click` action is triggered but if I add any views to `LinearLayout`, nothing happens.

Now the same scenario, if I `click` a `button`, which is inside fragment, it works perfectly. Same method, doesn't work(doesn't add views to `linearLayout`) when I click `Activity` `button`, but works when I click `fragment` `button`.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload the main view, you can detach then attach the fragment it do the trick :

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
         .beginTransaction()
         .detach(contentFragment)
         .attach(contentFragment)
         .commit();
```

Comment: But I am using the viewpager and adding the fragments in the FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: i see i know it's not the best solution but you can create a static method at your fragment that will make the view changes then call it from the button click

Comment: As it is a viewpager and by default 3 fragments will be alive at the same time, all 3 fragments will call the static method.

Comment: are using the same fragment class for all the 3 ?